# Expanding the Piecewise function at $(0,1;0)$ through Taylor series?

Tags: calculus, analysis, asymptotics, taylor-expansion, piecewise-continuity

$f_{r}(x,y;\xi) = f_{X} (x,y;\xi) $ when $y \leq g(x;\xi)$ and $f_{r}(x,y;\xi) = f_{Y} (x,y;\xi)$ when $y \geq g(x;\xi)$.

where $g(x;\xi) = 1 - p_{1}x - p_{3}\xi + O(x^2 + \xi^2)$ and $\xi$ is a real parameter.

$f_{r},g$ are $C^2$ functions.

To study $f_{X}$ and $f_{Y}$ near $(x,y) = (0,1)$ and for small values of $\xi$, we expand $f_{X}$ and $f_{Y}$ about $(x,y;\xi) = (0,1;0)$

Now since $f_{r}$ is continuous we have $f_{X} = f_{Y}$ on $y = g(x;\xi)$.

Now I am thinking about the next statement -

There exists constants $a_{1},a_{2},b_{1}^{X},b_{2}^{X},b_{1}^{Y},b_{2}^{Y},c_{1},c_{2} \in \Bbb{R}$ such that

$f_{S}(x,y;\xi) =  \begin{cases} 
      1 + (a_{1}+b_{1}^{S}p_{1})x + b_{1}^{S}(y-1)+(c_{1}+b_{1}^{S}p_{3})\xi+O(x^2+(y-1)^2+\xi^2)\\
      (a_{2}+b_{2}^Sp_{1})x+b_{2}^{S}(y-1)+(c_{2}+b_{2}^{S}p_{3})\xi +O(x^2+(y-1)^2+\xi^2)
   \end{cases}
$

$S =X,Y$

I think we are using Taylor series, If so how are we using it?. Is this correct? any help?

Comment: What is $\|x,\xi\|$ ??

Comment: I was trying to write the Big-Oh notation? I used \mathcal but couldnot do it?, it is actually BigOh$(||x,\xi||)$

Comment: What do we know about continuity of the derivatives ?

Comment: Still unclear. Do you mean the Euclidean norm of the vector $(x,\xi)$ ?

Comment: The derivatives of both the pieces must be the same at $(x,g(x;\xi))$? is this correct?

Comment: Yes it is the Euclidean norm, sorry for confusion

Comment: I can't guess for you, this belongs to the problem statement.

Comment: You could write $O(\sqrt{x^2+\xi^2})$ then.

Comment: I meant $\frac{\partial{f_{X}}}{\partial{x}} = \frac{\partial{f_{Y}}}{\partial{x}}$ and similarly for other variable $y$ too, when you said continuity of derivatives. I just did an edit regarding the Euclidean norm.

Comment: You say "since $f_r$ is continuous" but never stated that before. And even less for the derivatives.

Comment: Your big $O$ terms do not match the previous content.

Comment: You would male the notation easier by translating $y$ by $1$ to work around $(0,0;0)$.

Comment: Can I invite you to join the [Calculus and Analysis chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14150/calculus-and-analysis)?@YvesDaoust

Comment: Your handling of the $\xi$ parameter is weird. On one hand, you seem to consider it as a constant (due to the $;$) and on the other you want a development for "small $\xi$", around $0$. So I conclude that $\xi$ is just a third variable. Now you say nothing about continuity of the partials on $\xi$.

Comment: Sorry, no I don't chat.