# Continuous function that takes rationals to irrationals and vice-versa?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions, continuity, rational-numbers

In this question - https://www.quora.com/Can-you-create-a-continuous-function-that-takes-rational-numbers-to-irrational-ones-and-vice-versa

How $|f(\Bbb{Q})| \leq |\Bbb{Q}|$ ? in the first answer, I understood that $|f(\Bbb{Q}^c)| \leq |\Bbb{Q}|$ de to the fact that $|$Codomain$| \leq |$range$|$.

After that how do I think of this? - It then follows that f is a constant function because a non-constant continuous real-valued function has an uncountable image.

Also any other approach to this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably meant it the other way : the codomain is always larger than the range above.

Anyway, for a function, it can map every value in the domain to only *one* value in the range (that is, $f(x)$ is a unique value in the range), so in fact the range is also smaller than the domain . That is what the first statement reflects, since the domain is $\mathbb Q$ and the range is $f(\mathbb Q)$.

The other fact follows from the intermediate value theorem : if two distinct points $a < b$ are in the range of $f(\mathbb Q)$, then the entire range $[a,b]$ must belong to the range, by the fact that $f$ is continuous and hence the intermediate value theorem holds. it turns out that $[a,b]$ is uncountable if $a \neq b$, so $f(\mathbb Q)$ cannot contain two distinct points if it is countable: from here, $f(\mathbb Q)$ must be a single point, so $f$ is constant.

---

### Clarification on "domain larger than range"

The first thing that one shouldd keep in mind, especially with infinite sets, is that an infinite set may possibly have the same size as one of its subsets.

For example, $\{1,2,3,...\}$ is of the same size as $\{2,3,...\}$, because we have a bijection between the sets, given by the map $x \to x+1$. So, even though one set is contained in the other, they have the same size.

There is a way to look at the range as a "subset of the domain" : here's how we do  it . Fix any $x$ in the range. By definition of the range, there is a $y$ in the domain which maps to $x$.

As $x$ varies over the range, collect all the $y$s and put them together to form a subset of the domain. The point is, any two different $x$ s must be associated to different $y$ s, because $f(y)$ has a unique value, so $y$ cannot be associates to two different values.

This subset of the domain is at least as large as the range, because for each point of the range we found a different point in the domain to associate to. However, the domain itself is at least as large as this subset, and therefore as large as the range.

All this, completely ignores containment. Which means it is entirely possible that as sets in their own right, the domain is actually strictly contained in the range. What matters for us is the cardinality i.e. the size of both sets, and for this parameter I have shown that the domain is at least as large as the range in size, even though it may be contained in it.

Comment: Isi t always that cardinality of range is less than cardinality of domain?

Comment: Does a constant function fulfill the condition "codomain contains a rational and an irrational number"?

Comment: @BAYMAX Your statement is correct, but there is also another correct statement, and that is that the *domain* of a function also has larger size than the *range* of that function. So codomain $\geq$ range  and domain $\geq$ range are both correct statements. You are stating one of them : I am stating the other with brief justification.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг https://www.quora.com/Why-is-the-domain-larger-than-range-on-the-function-What-is-an-example, I am thinking which statement to consider?

Comment: @Maam The codomain is the real numbers , which of course contains both rationals and irrationals. The *range* is a single number in the case of a constant function, so clearly this does not fulfill any of the criteria. Consequently, there is *no* function that takes rationals to irrationals and irrationals to rationals, because we showed that any such function must be constant, but constant functions don't work.

Comment: @BAYMAX Can you find a bijection between the two sets given in the post i.e. $(0,\infty)$ and $(-\infty,\infty)$? Even if one is a subset of the other, there is no difference in their cardinality, because there is a bijection between the sets i.e. they are the same size. This might seem counterintuitive, but here's another example : $\{2,3,...\}$ has the same size as $\{1,2,3,...\}$, although it is contained in the latter. The statement I make is a statement of *size*, not of *containment* (i.e. range cannot have larger cardinality than domain), and I think I should make this more explicit.

Comment: @BAYMAX You may read my edit. The key point is to differentiate between "size" and "containment" as criteria for assessing two sets.

Comment: Thanks @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг, but why $[a,b]$ is uncountable? is it because in b/w $a$ and $b$, there are irrational numbers too? also how $f(\Bbb{Q})$ cannot contain two distinct points if it is countable?

Comment: @BAYMAX The fact that $[a,b]$ is countable  actually comes from the famous "Cantor diagonalization argument" that shows that $[0,1]$ is uncountable. I suggest you look it up :  it is a wonderful argument. Now, $[0,1]$ is in bijection with $[a,b]$, with $x \to a  + x(b-a)$, so we get that $[a,b]$ is also uncountable. As for your second point, if $a,b \in f(\mathbb Q)$, then by the intermediate value theorem , we have $[a,b] \subset f(\mathbb Q)$, which cannot happen as every subset of a countable set is countable, but $[a,b]$ is uncountable while $f(\mathbb Q)$ is countable.

Comment: I can understand if you have not heard of some terms in our discussion e.g. the diagonalization argument, which is usually discussed in a first course in real analysis. Please feel extremely free to clarify anything you want with me, and accept my/any other answer answer only when you are completely satisfied.

Comment: $[a,b] \subset f(\Bbb{Q}) \subset \Bbb{Q}$, so $[a,b]$ must be countable which is a contradiction, so we need $a=b$, the single point! hence a constant function!?@астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг is this correct?

Comment: Perfect, you have it in place correctly now. To completely finish the argument, you are looking for a continuous function which takes rationals to irrationals and vice-versa. We proved that any such function is a constant function, but a constant function takes every number, rational or irrational, to the same number, so it does not switch rationals and irrationals. Consequently, no such function exists.

Comment: Great!!!, that completely speaks everything!!, thanks for your time and help@астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг

Comment: You are welcome! Very happy to assist.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг If you are interested, I am happy to invite you to [Calculus and Analysis chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14150/calculus-and-analysis), also it would be much helpful if you could help me in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2900377/expanding-the-piecewise-function-at-0-10-through-taylor-series).

Comment: That one seems difficult at first sight : llet me have a look at it. Thank you for your invite.